# Bind reference to T& in both cases, std::optional<T> and T, at compile time

Tags: c++, constexpr, template-meta-programming, stdoptional

I have a function which takes a generic argument that can either be a `std::optional<T>` or `T` directly. For the further context of the function I don't care if the argument came in as an optional, I want to just be able to use a reference to the underlying value `T&`, which in case of the optional would mean I would have to conditionally extract the value using `std::optional::value()`. Can this be done generically? I thought I might be able to use an `std::reference_wrapper` to convert a constexpr conditional back to a reference, but it doesn't work. This is what I've got:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm27II/ioR9gmGgCCWzt7mIfHqEldzLSX13dm2wy7XgORzcXkctEIAE8vrd7v9Hs83E4RsRMKxoXdbgRMCwkgYsQiCBCkoxWJhSPssTi8U9gYTicw2AA6ZmXfa7JgKBTo5FeBz7PAKAD6CmJyDwYjwAC8mO9BagqPsQPsziAQFQxEpBXSaQB2Kw6gAiRysMMx2NxMppx0pFvxtKJJKZLM22DZBk5%2BwAKubqeTtQzMMzGfsbsRgApnldbjy%2BQLhaLxeDpbL5cDvVTLcDQ%2BGg5dyenbZhWUqVSACMQvJgtQ7DnqTIbjd9vjbqQSHQGvX6fZa2/TSbmXW6ORGC9T0Wh/pg3sqExLkxk5Qqjgb%2BUKRdVE1KZQvU8dPfnu1jLqqAG5iSuN00Ym6hAj7FhMUIQea1k03fYf5UEdCq17vMTArerIsBCf7PCuZiXten5sgIIz7EwoIXGYABs%2BwokumwriYACsViobhRp1rcMGkZ%2BeAKhOIyYKoSTEPsEDrmKc7bgIi7AlguzahAIF/osX4/iAf4ZABLovvWb5kVJn4ogQKwMAJqrIBhPGgW8jJnt4mDPvMUHSTB9Yrh0Sivt8%2BlSbJ8mKSgKm8W8umbJJ5m1kaJFSYZz5QWZn6lmgoIIsC6GYJhbiBb5ywEF5hocIstCcDhvB%2BBwWikKgnChZY1jKssqw0r8PCkAQmgxYsADWIA4Ro%2BicJIiXFalnC8AoIBVUVyUxaQcCwDAiAoKgOJ0LE5CUGgA30HEwBcJsbRYCeeBrAAangmAAO4APL0pwBU0LQWLEM1EBRPVUShA0EJbbwJ3MMQEJrVE2jVG1BWjWwghrQwtDne1pBYFEXjAG4Yi0M13C8FgD5GOI334CiNQnpgIMpTR1SgusKW3h09XglExBnR4WD1eWeAsBdixUAY4ZLatG2MBdMiCCIYjsFI9PyEoaj1bobQGEYKDWNY%2Bh4FEzWQIswlwZwAC0ZzLqYmWWGYGj7JLa0KLwqDw8QxB4FgIvPu0nQZC4DDuJ4LR6MEoQDKUQxtCkaTvOMrR5A7GQzIMcSTB0j21KMTRmxMBs%2B90fvuzbnu2H7TvDKHVuzLbiwKDlawLNVHAJaQSUpWlHD7Ko8QoZLKGSPswDIMg%2BxTYyXAMbghAkIc%2BXzLwbVaPMZUVVVcUcLVpAkzhkiMpIACcOrDxoY8j2PE/D5n9U501LWFcVixdb1EVJKCw0QKNSSDcQ4Skpw%2BeF8Xpfl5XmzV7wmD4EQ2s/m0/AM6I4gs8/bMqOo31c6QK240kUmacM5Z3VpwNaoJN53nlHnAuRcS5lwrlXGuEAPBjViI3aazdl7tXbqQBAqIsBxH1t3XuJNJA4UZJVRWw9FbUI0LQtooCGocEXq1FeHdKpp02HVb6C8cFt1ipwMwvDs6NQESVUgms0jOEkEAA%3D%3D):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <optional>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename, template <typename...> class>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args >
struct is_specialization_of<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class Template>
concept specialization_of = is_specialization_of<T, Template>::value;


int main() {
    std::optional<int> myopt = 2;

    const auto& ref = [&]{
            if constexpr (specialization_of<decltype(myopt), std::optional>) {
                return std::cref(myopt.value());
            } else {
                return std::cref(myopt);
            }
        }();

    std::cout << ref << std::cout;
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:27:22: error: no match for 'operator<<'
```

... of sorts and more. Why do I want this? Because I don't want to adapt every passage in the code to either adapt to `T`'s or `std::optional<T>`'s interface because the verbosity of that would be rampant...

Note: I also tried the non-autodeduced reference: `const int& ref = ...` but with the same result.

Comment: why use `std::cref` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I originally had in mind that function must return the same type and somehow thought I could unify the type with cref, but obviously that would be type erasure and types are the same in any case so... no reason really

Comment: [What if `T` is itself `std::optional<U>`](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2018/12/09/deducing-your-intentions/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `std::reference_wrapper` here, simply declare your lambda to return a reference:

```
const auto& ref = [&]() -> auto& {
            if constexpr (specialization_of<decltype(myopt), std::optional>) {
                return myopt.value();
            } else {
                return myopt;
            }
        }();
```

Furthermore I would advise you to not use a fancy `specialization_of` template in favor of simple function overloading:

```
template <typename T>
T const& extract_value(T const& t) { return t; }

template <typename T>
T const& extract_value(std::optional<T> const& t) { 
    return extract_value(t.value()); // Recurse to handle the case where T is std::optional<U>
}  

int main() {
    std::optional<int> myopt = 2;
    const auto& ref = extract_value(myopt);
    std::cout << ref << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Oh I'm stupid i wrote std::cout twice haha, I think the error is unrelated x_X

Comment: @JanSchultke That is not necessary, `auto&` will deduce as `int const&`